# FullCalendar exibido em horário errado

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

Estou implementar o `FullCalendar` em um projeto, fiz a inserção de alguns *Eventos* no banco de dados e retorno-os via `Json`. Porém ao exibi-los na tela, eles vem com a data horário corretos, mas a exibição não mostra no lugar correto.

Exemplo, os dados vem com a data do banco de inicio do evento as 06:00, mas são exibidos as 10:00 da manhã.

Na imagem abaixo, o evento tem horario de inicio as 06:30, e término as 07:00.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas ele mostra na tela que o horario é as 10:30
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu model `Eventos`:

```
 public class Eventos
 {
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public DateTime start { get; set; }
    public DateTime? end { get; set; }
    public int StatusEnum { get; set; }
 }
```

Meu método que busca os dados estão assim:

```
public JsonResult ObterEventos(string start, string end)
{
    var db = new AgendaOnlineFc();
    var dtInicial = Convert.ToDateTime(start).Date;
    var dtfinal = Convert.ToDateTime(end).Date;
    var lista = db.Eventos
        .Where(d => d.end < dtfinal && d.start > dtInicial)
        .ToList();
    return Json(lista, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

O retorno do meu `Json` está assim:

```
{ID: 10, title: "teste", start: "/Date(1495449000000)/", end: "/Date(1495450800000)/", StatusEnum: 0}
ID:10
StatusEnum:0
end:"/Date(1495450800000)/"
start:"/Date(1495449000000)/"
title:"teste"
```

e meu `Script`,

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: '/Home/ObterEventos/'
});
```

Existe alguma configuração adicional a ser feita ? 
Ou se não onde estou errando nessa implementação ?

Comment: Olá Renan, por favor adicione um print mostrando como a data está chegando ao navegador

Answer (score 4):

Isso é problema de Timezone errada. Importei as datas aqui (meu horário é GMT-5) e tive valores diferentes também.

Um pacote que corrige isso é o [Moment Timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/). Fiz o seguinte teste e imprimiu as datas no horário certo (o que você registrou em banco):

```
> moment("/Date(1495449000000)/").tz('America/Sao_Paulo').format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
< "2017-05-22 06:30:00"
```

---

**EDIT**

Você pode também definir no *Controller* ancestral (método `Initialize`) a seguinte configuração, se quiser que o C# faça a conversão para você:

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat,
    DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Local
};
```