# Modificar retorno de função em FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

Estou tentando fazer um `script` que vá até meu banco de dados e retorne os dados através de uma função. 
Segue:

```js
events: function(start, end, timezone) {
  // var convert = 
  moment(start).tz("America/Cuiaba").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");
  $.ajax({
    url: "/Home/Eventos",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
      start: start.unix(),
      end: end.unix()
    },
    success: function(doc) {
      var events = [];
      $(doc).find('event').each(function() {
        var start = moment(doc.start).tz("America/Cuiaba").format("HH:mm");
        var end = moment(doc.end).tz("America/Cuiaba").format("HH:mm");
        events.push({
          title: $(this).attr('title'),
          start: start,
          end: end // will be parsed
        });;
      });
    }
  });
},
```

O Script completo com o calendar está [aqui](https://gist.github.com/Renancp01/2068dc97bd75a4589a85470651386cc3). Inseri num *Gist* pra não ficar muito extenso.

Comment: Poderia por a parte do fullcalendar?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento editei a pergunta, inserindo todo meu código com `scripts` e tem esta outra [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/206492/fullcalendar-exibido-em-hor%C3%A1rio-errado) aqui também que está relacionada.